# How to get list of USB in winform using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, usb, usb-drive

i have tried this code to get the usb devices in connected to the computer.
This is the code:

```
 foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
 {
     if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
     {
        cmbUSB.Items.Add(drive.Name);
     }
 }
```

cmbusb is a combobox.. here i am getting this :

```
 E:/
 G:/
```

but not getting the device name, like :

```
 E:/Insforia
```

something like this,
how can i get this? is it possible to get this? pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [VolumeLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel.aspx), try:

> The label length is determined by the operating system. For example,
>   NTFS allows a volume label to be up to 32 characters long. Note that
>   null is a valid VolumeLabel.

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
 {
     if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
     {
        if (drive.IsReady)
                 cmbUSB.Items.Add(drive.Name + "-" + drive.VolumeLabel);
                                                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                     //here   
     }
 }
```

Comment: @ArindamDas, you can add a check to see if drive is ready like `if (drive.IsReady)`

Answer (score 3):

For getting the DeviceName of E:/ try this.

```
DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo("E"); 
if(driveInfo.IsReady) 
{ 
    string deviceName = driveInfo.VolumeLabel; 
}
```

Comment: Chec whether the drive is ready or not. i have edited the answer.